# Getting error while linking with g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, linker, compilation

I try to compile and link my application in 2 steps :

Compiling:

> g++ -c -o file1.o file1.cc general_header.h
>   g++ -c -o file2.o file2.cc general_header.h
>   g++ -c -o file3.o file3.cc general_header.h

Linking:

> g++ -o myApp file1.o file2.o file3.o

I'm getting a link error as following:

> file1.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Am i doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to include header files in your input files list

`g++ -c -o file1.o file1.cc`

Answer (score 3):

You should not be mentioning your header file on the command line - you don't want to compile it directly, but only as it is included in your source files. also, I would let the compiler name the object files, as it's too easy to make a typo when doing this explicitly.  So your compilation commands should look like:

```
g++ -c file1.cc
```

and you can then also say:

```
g++ -c file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc
```